# How to refer a static resource in on war file from other war file?

Tags: css, web, shared-libraries, war, weblogic-10.x

I currently have an application deployed in WebLogic Server Version: 10.3.6.0 as a WAR.
I have a css file style.css which is referenced from an html file(index.html) inside the same war.

Is it possible to have the same css file with the same file name in another war file which is deployed as a shared library and in the weblogic.xml of application add a reference to this shared library and refer the css file in the shared library war from index.html??

Comment: Yes you should be able to do it no problem. See this blog post that shows how to do it with an image file: https://blogs.oracle.com/jamesbayer/entry/weblogic_server_shared_librari

Comment: I have a **index.html** page which has link to **style.css**, both are packaged in war(Application war). In shared library war when I added the file **style.css** with same name but different content the application still referring to the file in the Application war and not the file in the shared library war. How to make it refer to the **style.css** in the shared library war?